# Getting all values for [EventLoopFuture] before proceeding

Tags: swift, promise, future, vapor, swift-nio

I have an array of values I map to multiple promises that give me each a EventLoopFuture. So I end up with a method that has a variable-size [EventLoopFuture], and I need all the responses to succeed before I can continue. If one or more of them returns an error, I need to perform the error scenario.

How can I await the entire [EventLoopFuture] to complete before continuing with either the succeed path or error path?

Comment: Thank you so much for the great and detailed answers, imike and johannes-weiss. Unfortunately SO doesn't have a way of marking both answers as the right answer, or I would have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`EventLoopFuture`'s got a [`reduce(into: ...)`](https://apple.github.io/swift-nio/docs/current/NIO/Classes/EventLoopFuture.html#/s:3NIO15EventLoopFutureC6reduce4into_2on_ACyxGx_SayACyqd__GGAA0bC0_pyxz_qd__tctlFZ) method that can be used quite well for that purpose (and other tasks where you want to accumulate multiple values):

```
let futureOfStrings: EventLoopFuture<[String]> =
    EventLoopFuture<String>.reduce(into: Array<String>(),
                                   futures: myArrayFutureStrings,
                                   on: someEventLoop,
                                   { array, nextValue in array.append(nextValue) })
```

To specifically turn `[EventLoopFuture<Something>]` into `EventLoopFuture<[Something]>` you can also use the shorter [`whenAllSucceed`](https://apple.github.io/swift-nio/docs/current/NIO/Classes/EventLoopFuture.html#/s:3NIO15EventLoopFutureC14whenAllSucceed_2onACySayxGGSayACyxGG_AA0bC0_ptFZ)

```
let futureOfStrings: EventLoopFuture<[String]> =
    EventLoopFuture<String>.whenAllSucceed(myStringFutures, on: someEventLoop)
```

Answer (score 3):

Waiting for all futures in array is possible with `flatten` like this

```swift
[future1, future2, future3, future4].flatten(on: eventLoop)
```

for `flatten` each future should return `Void` and `flatten` itself will return `EventLoopFuture<Void>`

sometimes we need to process some array with simple values and do something with each value using some method which returns `EventLoopFuture` and in this case the code may look like this

```swift
let array = ["New York", "Los Angeles", "Las Vegas"]

array.map { city in
     someOtherMethod(city).transform(to: ())
}.flatten(on: eventLoop)
```

in the example above method `someOtherMethod` can return future with anything but we can transform it to `EventLoopFuture<Void>` to use with `flatten`